# Running a background service to fetch data from firebase database and performing certain action if particular value is received in the UI

Tags: android, firebase, background

I am quite new to android development.I am using a sensor to update a value continuously in the database.I want to run a service continuously in background even if the app is not opened and if any abnormal value is received (unusual value) from firebase I want to start an alarm system so that the user knows what is the value and is made aware.

I tried worker class,Jobscheduler,AsyncTask but without i was find difficulty to implement any of them as the data received was not being able to setText on the textView inspite of several attempts.

I request to guide me through this to develop such an app to get data from service and perform the action required.

Comment: Are you able to successfully run a background service?

Comment: You should use Cloud Functions to achieve what you want. Please check the duplicate.

Comment: yes it runs but i can't settext the data received on any textView  I used bundle to pass data from service to mainactivity it works but not fully.